# SQLite + setAdapter = NPE

Tags: java

There is a NPE at the last line, I can't figure out where it's coming from. Any ideas?

```
  mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
  mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
  listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
  Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
  startManagingCursor(cursor);

  String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CHOICE,         
  SQLiteAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT};
  int[] to = new int[]{R.id.txtChoice, R.id.txtAmtSpent};

  SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
   new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row2, cursor, from, to);
  mySQLiteAdapter.close();
  listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

HERE IS THE ERROR

```
    06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whycom.idontknow/com.whycom.idontknow.ListSpent}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at com.whycom.idontknow.ListSpent.makeList(ListSpent.java:161)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at com.whycom.idontknow.ListSpent.onCreate(ListSpent.java:79)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-19 01:27:50.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1425):     ... 11 more
```

The whole code is below:

```
 package com.whycom.idontknow;
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ListSpent extends ListActivity {
    private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
    //Intent splat;
    //Bundle b;

    //  String[] amounts;
    //  String[] expenditureArray;
    String choice; 
    String amount; 
    int count;
    String[] dataAry= new String[100];
    //String[] choices;
    String Count;
    SharedPreferences prefs; 
    TextView txtAmtSpent;
    TextView txtChoice;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ListView listContent;
    int j;
//  ListView listContent;


    //      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlist);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
        initVars();
        try {
            buildArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        makeList();
    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView text;
        TextView button;
    }



    public void buildArray() throws IOException{
        //ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        InputStream instream;
        try {
            instream = openFileInput("mySpends.txt");
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

            Count = prefs.getString("Count" , "0");
            count = Integer.parseInt(Count);





            for (int i = 0; i < ((count)*2); i=i+2){
                choice = buffreader.readLine();
                amount = buffreader.readLine();
                dataAry[i] = choice;
                dataAry[i+1] = amount;
                //trial

            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    private void initVars(){

        txtAmtSpent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAmtSpent);
        txtChoice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtChoice);
        listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

    }


    private void makeList(){
         mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
          mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
          mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
        ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
        String [] dataAryArray = new String[(count)*2];
        j = 0;
        int ind = (count)*2-1;
        for (int i = -1; i < ind; ind = ind - 2){
            dataAryArray[j] = dataAry[ind];
            dataAryArray[j+1] = dataAry[ind-1];

              mySQLiteAdapter.insert(dataAryArray[j],dataAryArray[j+1]);

            j=j+2;


        }
         mySQLiteAdapter.close();

          mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
          Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
          startManagingCursor(cursor);
          String c=SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CHOICE;
          String a=SQLiteAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT;
          String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CHOICE, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT};
          int[] to = new int[]{R.id.txtChoice, R.id.txtAmtSpent};

          SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
           new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.id.text, cursor, from, to);

          listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
          mySQLiteAdapter.close();






        //      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        //              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataAryArray);
        //      setListAdapter(adapter);            
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                //       When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                //              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                //                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        )
        ;
    }

}
```

Here is the XML named mainlist.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >
     <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/hello"
       />
     <ListView
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listContent` is not found.
You may need to call `setContentView` before trying `findViewById`.

---

Update

Based on more information and provided code, since your declared ListView id

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

it refers to Android id not your own. So you need to search for it via

```
findViewById(android.R.id.list)
```

not your package R.

But why would you even need it if ListActivity provides all methods so you don't have to access it directly? For example,

```
setListAdapter(...);
```

See example here http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/

Comment: what do i setContentView to? if i set it to r.layout.list it gives me     06-18 22:37:31.698: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17080): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: sorry, I put the wrong code in there, this is the code im having trouble with

Comment: Please clarify: your new code already includes `setContentView` did you add it after my answer? Which exception do you get now? NPE or `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`?

Comment: NPE at listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

Comment: Is your xml name list.xml and placed in res/layout?

Comment: I updated the answer. You refer to incorrect list id, I think.

Comment: i updated code, this is what i'm getting now.. i haven't tried your answer yet.. will let you know

Comment: when i do a debug i see that listcontent is null.. coudl that be it? if so how do i fix it?

Comment: That's exactly the point from the beginning. You specified id that can't be found, so I got null.

Comment: i changed to ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);    now i get resources not found exception

Comment: As I said in my update - you don't need it at all. Just use `setListAdapter` and remove this findViewById. The idea of using ListActivity is that you don't need to access list directly.

Comment: when i do that i get 06-19 02:04:50.322: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2460): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f05000e type #0x12 is not valid
:(

Comment: It's probably the same error as if you try to use listContent directly. But without stack trace, it's almost impossible to figure out the problem. I'd say try to look in android.R and find constant #0x7f05000e and see what it is.

Comment: eesh, how do i provide a stack trace? and thx very much for ur help.. #0x7f05000e refers to public static final int text=0x7f05000e;

Comment: Here: `new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.id.text, cursor, from, to);` you actually need to give it layout, not id. Usually you want to create separate layout for your list item and give it here.

Comment: yay! this seemed to have helped! but it isnt displaying the values i need it to.. i'll have to look this one over some more.. I'm loading the sqlite table from an array...

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful to include the stack trace for the NPE. But I suspect the problem might be this line, immediately before the NPE:

```
  mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

If the `SQLiteAdapter` class is similar to the `NotesDbAdapter` class from the Android [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html), then you shouldn't be closing it there; that will invalidate your cursor. Instead, close it in your activity's [onDestroy](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-closing-those-database-objects/) method. (That last link goes to a blog post that I wrote regarding when and how to close these objects.)

Comment: i don't have an onDestroy method.. I am using this tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html

Comment: @tricknology: Every Activity **can** have an onDestroy method. However, the activities in the Notepad tutorial did not have them, although they **should** have had them. I think this omission spread to other tutorials that were based (however loosely) on that one. And likewise, I think your activity needs to have one. Have a look at my blog post, which has a simple example. And please give it a try in your app.

Comment: @tricknology: I just looked at the tutorial you're using -- it follows that same pattern that I described. Notice, though, that it calls `mySQLiteAdapter.close()` **after** calling       `listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter)`. I think this is probably still wrong, but it's less likely to lead to an immediate NPE. (It might produce an NPE later on, though, perhaps when scrolling through the list.)

Comment: Dan, I took a look at your example but I don't think it applies to me, I dont get the same error message.. jsut a null pointer. when i do a debug i see that listcontent is null.. coudl that be it? if so how do i fix it?

Comment: @tricknology: Have you *tried* the suggestion that I made? You mentioned in another comment that it's not displaying the right values, even after you've gotten past the NPE. This may well be why. If you're able to get the whole thing working without making this change, then honestly, I'll be surprised; I'd really like to hear if you do.

Comment: @Dan: it's working fine :-) I had to muddle around in my sqladapter and xml files but it displays the values just fine :) do you know of any "easy" resources for charts?